# Display values on click

Tags: html

I wish to design a table with single row and 2 columns. When I click on the value in cell A1, I want its description to be displayed in A2.For example if A1 contains B,A2 would display Bat,only when I click on B. What is the easiest way to achieve this using HTML coding?

Comment: are you able to use javascript? html does not have onClick events.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to try javascript you can try this out.

```js
// will check the answer closest to clue and show it in the next td
$(".clue").on("click", function(){

  // get the answer 'Bat' in this case.
  var answer = $(this).closest("tr").find(".answer").attr("data-id");

  // put 'Bat' in the next td with the class answer.
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".answer").html(answer);

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.clue:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="clue">
      B
    </td>
    <td class="answer" data-id="Bat"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the click, and hovering is okay, you can do it without JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Hover Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
                td+td       { font-size: 0; }
                td:hover+td { font-size: 1em; transition: 2s; }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Hover Test</h1>
        <table>
                <tr> <td>B</td> <td>Bat</td> </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```